# Limit the content cappabilities for user roles of subscriptions

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, user-roles, limit, subscription

I need guide to builld a subscription page payed by monthly having (bronce,silver,gold) subscriptions as a roles users.

the bronce role can create and edit one an only (1  template page ) that page can going published for everyone to the public.
same as the other 2 roles, for silver they can publish 2 and  golds canpublish 3.
how can limit his roles permissions to acces the edit but just for 1,2,3 creations of a page/s acoording to their plan.
iam using wordpress , divi role editor and advanced-access -mannager (https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager).

similar to linktree.

If can anyone help ewith the right way. best regaras and thank you for your time

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.